# VS2015 UnitTest host process is always 32-bit, ignoring Default Process Architecture setting

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++

I created a native test DLL project from template "Native Unit Test Project" in VS2015 update 3. This project is set to x64 build.

By default, Test -> Test Settings -> Default Process Architecture is x86. So I get the error when run the test:

> Result Message:   A 64-bit test cannot run in a 32-bit process. Specify
>   platform as X64 to force test run in X64 mode on X64 machine.

But I still get the error when I changed Default Process Architecture to x64. How do I diagnose and fix the problem?